# Batch: How to start and kill a specific node process

Tags: node.js, batch-file, process

From a batch script, how do I start and exit a specific node app?

---

Example:

Having `main_to_continue.js` that should survive and `main_to_be_stopped.js` that should be waited for a specific time and then get exited.

We need a replacement for the TASKKILL or some way to trace the main_to_be_stopped.js.

```
START node main_to_continue.js
START node main_to_be_stopped.js
TIMEOUT 5
REM following would kill both apps, however we want to only kill the second
REM TASKKILL /IM node.exe /F
```

Comment: `wmic process where commandline='"c:\\windows\\notepad.exe" c:\\windows\\win.ini' get /format:list` will identify processes by command line. `wmic process where commandline='"c:\\windows\\notepad.exe" c:\\windows\\win.ini' call terminate` will kill matching command lines.

Comment: Thanks, that works, for this case it's ```wmic process where 'commandline like "%to_be_stopped%"' call terminate```, I would mark it solved if you'd add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WMIC can filter on `CommandLine` unlike other termination tools.

```
wmic process where commandline='"c:\\windows\\notepad.exe" c:\\windows\\win.ini' get /format:list
```

will identify processes by command line.

```
wmic process where commandline='"c:\\windows\\notepad.exe" c:\\windows\\win.ini' call terminate
```

will kill matching command lines.

Type `wmic /?`, `wmic process get /?`, `wmic process call /?`.